# Create a stream of consecutive values that pass a filter

Tags: functional-programming, rxjs, reactive-programming, reactivex

Say I have a stream of numbers

---1-----1----1----0----0----1----1----0--->

And i want to get a new stream of arrays containing consecutive 1's like this

---[1,1,1]---[1,1]--->

I though of using the scan function but that only emits one value and I read about bufferToggle but documentation only uses it with timed observables. Is there any function that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is to use `scan` with the `pairwise` operator.

Using pairwise you can compare the `N-1`th emission to the `N`th.

```js
console.clear();
var source = Rx.Observable.of(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0);

source
  .concat(Rx.Observable.of(0)) // for the case when source completes with 1
  .scan(function(acc, x) {
    // reset accumulator to an empty array when a 0 is encountered
    if (x === 0) {
      return [];
    } else {
      return acc.concat([x]);
    }
  }, [])
  .pairwise()
  // filter when the accumulated value goes from a length greater than 0
  // to 0 then you know you've hit 0
  .filter((pair) => pair[0].length > 0 && pair[1].length === 0)
  // take the first element of the pair since it has the result you're interested in
  .map((pair) => pair[0])
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice solution. I'd add a `.concat(Observable.of(0))` before `.scan`, though, otherwise the result will not emit if the source stream ends with a 1, e.g. the source `Observable.of(1, 1, 1)` will not emit anything at all.

Comment: Good catch @ehrencrona. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use the source itself as a signal for [`bufferToggle`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferToggle) - which uses observables to control the opening and closing of the buffer.

However, you have to be careful with the order in which subscriptions are made to the source. In particular, the observables used to signal the opening and closing of the buffer must be subscribed *before* the `bufferToggle` observable subscribes.

This can be done using `publish` and a `Subject`, like this:

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.of(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0);
const published = source.publish();

const signal = new Rx.Subject();
published.subscribe(signal);

const buffered = published.bufferToggle(
  signal
    .startWith(0)
    .pairwise()
    .filter(([prev, last]) => (prev === 0) && (last === 1)),
  () => signal.filter(value => value === 0)
);

buffered.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
published.connect();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

The `Subject` is required because each time a value is emitted, a subscription is made to the observable used to signal the closing of the buffer.

*I should add that I submitted this answer not because I think it's better than the other answer, but to show that it is possible to use the* `buffer` *(and* `window` *) operators with a signal that's derived from the source. Some care must be taken, that's all. With RxJS, there's often more than one way to do something.*

*Also, it's easy to create a [re-usable, lettable/pipeable operator](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/master/source/let/prioritize.ts) to help with these situations.*